# Can I use debdelta to install/update single package?

Tags: updates, software-installation, debdelta

`debdelta-upgrade` can be used to upgrade whole system, while saving time and bandwidth.The `debdelta-upgrade` man page says,

```
debdelta-upgrade  -  Downloads  all deltas that may be used to 'apt-get
upgrade', and apply them.
```

But can I use `debdelta` or `debdelta-upgrade` to install/update single package?

Comment: As far as I know, Ubuntu is still using gzip which doesn't work very well with deltas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`debdelta` works by downloading incremental changes between packages and patching the installed data. In theory you could:

- Install the original version of a package (using `apt-cache policy` and the `apt-get install package==version` syntax)
- Upgrade with `debdelta`

But that's a silly idea. The sum filesize of the original archive plus all the incremental updates will be *far* in excess of an updated package. Plus the CPU time required to install it is *much* higher.

If you have a locally centralised copy of packages (like an out-of-date mirror), I can start to appreciate why you might want to do this but again, if there's more than one client computer involved, updating that mirror seems like a better solution.

---

Purely from a syntax point of view, this is from `man debdelta-upgrade`:

```
debdelta-upgrade [OPTION]... [PACKAGE] ...
```

You can specify one or many packages if you want to limit the upgrade.

Comment: But in cases when I already have one installed and want to update it, can I use `debdelta`?

Comment: I think I see what you're asking. I've added to my answer.